# Number of solutions of a given equation analytically

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

> How many real solutions are there of the equation $2^x+5^x=3^x+4^x$ ?

Clearly it shows that $x=0$ and $x=1$ are two solutions of the given equation. Now how can I conclude that there are exactly two solutions?

If we take $f(x)=2^x+5^x-3^x-4^x$ and suppose there are $3$ solutions. Then the derivative of $f(x)$ must vanishes at least two points. But I'm unable to show that!

Any hint for this?

Comment: There are only two real solutions.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner How can you conclude that? Yeah, there are two, I've checked by software. But analytically how?

Comment: Related:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645742/solving-an-exponential-equation-with-different-bases

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to find $a$ and $b$ such that $5^x > 3^x + 4^x$ for $x > b$ and $2^x > 3^x + 4^x$ for $x < a$.  That cuts you down to a finite interval $[a,b]$.  If $f(x) = 2^x + 5^x - 3^x - 4^x$, you should be able to use estimates on $f$ and $f'$ to cover $[a,b]$ by 
finitely many intervals on which either $f(x)$ is bounded away from $0$, or the interval contains $0$ or $1$ and $f'(x)$ is bounded away from $0$.

Alternatively, take a simple positively-oriented closed contour $\Gamma$ in the complex plane that has the interval $[a,b]$ inside it, and evaluate 
$$N = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\Gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\; dz$$
with enough precision to show that it can't be $3$ or more.

Comment: How can I show that integration value can never be more than $2$ ?

Comment: It's an integer.  If it's less than $3$, it can't be more than $2$.

Comment: Yes. But my question is, how can I show that it is less than $3$ ?

Comment: Numerical integration with a bound on the error.