# Integer solutions for $2^x+5^x=3^x+4^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function

How many integer solutions exist for the equation $2^x+5^x=3^x+4^x$?

**Attempt:**
Clearly, $x=0$ is a solution.
Then, I divided both sides by $5^x$ to get;
$$\left(\frac 25\right)^x+1=\left(\frac 35\right)^x+\left(\frac 45\right)^x$$
It is easy to see that the left hand side of this equation is always greater than $1$. Moreover, taking a first derivative on the right hand side, it is easy to see that it is a decreasing function, which attains value $1$ at $x=2$. Thus, for $x>2$, RHS$<1$ while LHS$>1$, so no solutions exist, and the only natural solutions for $x$ are, trivially, $x=0,1$.

But I am struggling with the case where $x<0$. Can anyone please help with that? I also see that the bases on both sides have sum equal to $7$, which makes me think that some kind of inequality might be involved, but I am unable to proceed that way.

**Edit:** It would be helpful to see a solution that exploits the integer constraint.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645742/solving-an-exponential-equation-with-different-bases

Comment: When $x<0$, multiply both sides by $12^{-x}$ and then consider both sides mod 2?

Comment: If $x < 0$ let $x = -y$ and then multiply both sides but $2^y$ to get $1 + (\frac 25)^y = (\frac 23)^y + (\frac 12)^y$ and do the same.  Does it lead to any issues that a difficult to resolve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving an exponential equation with different bases](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645742/solving-an-exponential-equation-with-different-bases)

Comment: @Wolgwang thanks, but I'd like to know if I could proceed with my solution as well.

Comment: ... if $x =-y = 1$ then $\frac 23 + \frac 12 = 1\frac 16\ne 1 \frac 25$ and for $y=2$ we have $\frac 49 +\frac 14 < 1 < 1+\frac 4{25}$ and by derivative it is a decreasing function (or $y$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solutions in the link provided answer a different question--nonintegral $x$, and so are not helpful here. For $x$ integral, there is a much simpler observation.

For $x$ a negative integer, note that $2^x > 3^x+4^x$ for all integers $x \le -3$ [you can show this by induction], so if $x$ is nonpositive, then $|x|$ must be no larger than $2$.

Likewise for $x$ a positive integer, note that $5^x > 3^x+4^x$  for all $x \ge 3$ [you can show this by induction as well], so $x$ must also be no larger than $2$.

So all this leaves you to check is which $x \in \{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$ satisfy this equation.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I'll accept your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there were an integer solution $x<0$. Then multiply both sides by $12^{-x}$ to get

$$30^{-x} + 12^{-x} = 20^{-x} + 15^{-x}$$
or
$$0 \equiv 1 \pmod 2,$$
a contradiction.

Comment: But are modulo classes defined if we aren't dealing with integers? I mean, the expressions on either side of the equation may not be integers.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Why not? You are restricting $x$ to be an integer, no? (If $x$ is a negative integer, then $-x$ is positive and all terms are integers in the top equation.)

Comment: "But are modulo classes defined if we aren't dealing with integers?"  You ARE dealing with integers.  If $x < 0; x\in \mathbb Z$ then $-x > 0$ and $-x \in \mathbb N$.  SO $30^{-x}, 12^{-x}, 20^{-x} , 15^{-x}$ are all integers.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks (+1)

Answer (score 2):

If $x < 0$ replace $x$ with $-y$ and get

$2^{-y} + 5^{-y} = 3^{-y} + 4^{-y}$ and

$(\frac 12)^y + (\frac 15)^y = (\frac 13)^y + (\frac 14)^y$ and to get fractions $\le 1$ multiply all sides by $2^y$ and do what you did before.

$1 + (\frac 25)^y \ge 1$ and $(\frac 23)^y + (\frac 12)^y$ is, by derivative, a decreasing function.

For $y = 1$ we don't have a solution ($1+\frac 25 \ne \frac 23 + \frac 12$) and for $y \ge 2$ we have $(\frac 23)^y + (\frac 12)^y \le \frac 49 +\frac 14 < 1 < 1+(\frac 25)^y$.

So no negative integer solutions either.

So only integer solution is $x = 0$.

Comment: This is incorrect. $x=1$ is also a solution.